# A default www.conf somehow always appear in /etc/php-fpm.d/, so my main website .conf file got confused because of the same port, How do i fix this?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, centos7

I have a Centos 7, Nginx, Php-fpm web server.

Somehow a default www.conf file just appear out of nowhere in /etc/php-fpm.d/ even when i deleted the file (rm www.conf).

My main .conf file got confused because the www.conf use the same port that it listen to, so i'm getting a 502 bad gateway error on the browser.

How do i troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't delete files that are installed as part of an RPM package and expect them to stay gone. `www.conf` is part of your package management system's PHP-FPM package – if it's missing, it will be replaced every time there's an update.

Put your configuration into this file, or if you really don't want to use it for some reason, just erase its contents and leave the empty file in place. Next time there's an update your package manager (e.g. `yum`) will just put the default file in the directory as `www.conf.rpmnew` and it won't be parsed.

Comment: Thank you, i just check that there was a yum cron running. I'm going to disable the auto update and i will rename the www.conf file as you told me to do so.

You are very helpful. Regards.